# how to customize otp screen in digits(fabric)?

Tags: android

I have gone through the docs,but couldn't find any thing.Only theme customization is mentioned.I would like to customize it according to the look and feel of my app.

Docs-       https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/theming.html